# Issue with Chrome calling cross domain jsonp resource via jQuery ajax

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

## solved - it was Adblock Plus

I have a cross-domain OAuth scenario where I'm calling OAuth protected jsonp resources on a 3rd party api directly from JavaScript.

The client relies on my server (the site of origin) to generate signed request urls for OAuth resources on the provider. The client GETs these OAuth resources directly in an attempt to limit OAuth proxy duties of my server to simply generating signed resource urls and letting JS do the rest. Here's the JS:

```
myNamespace = {
    callApi: function(signedRequest, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: signedRequest,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: callback,
            cache: true,
            async: true
        });
    },
    usersCallback: function(jsonp) {
        alert(jsonp);
    },
    getOAuthResource: function(resource, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/GetSignedRequest?resource=" +  encodeURIComponent(resource + "&callback=" + callback),
            success: function (signedRequest) {
                myNamespace.callApi(signedRequest, callback);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Because the parameter order matters when signing the request, I include the callback manually so that it gets ordered & included in the signed request the server generates.

So an example usage would be simply,

```
myNamespace.getOAuthResource("/users?id=1", "myNamespace.usersCallback");
```

This is working in FireFox 20 and IE 10 - I get the alert msg & the expected json from the provider.

Chrome 26 refuses to perform the cross-domain call to the provider. In dev tools, the GET for the cross-domain resource immediately shows a Status of "(failed)" and the GET shows up in the console as an error.

If I subsequently ask Chrome to open this supposedly "failed" URL in a new window, it re-requests the URL directly on the provider and I get the expected jsonp response:

```
myNamespace.usersCallback({...})
```

Why won't Chrome perform the cross-domain call?

Comment: The "Adblock Plus" extension for Chrome was blocking the GET for the cross-domain JSONP scripts. I'm too new to answer my own q's on StackOverflow, but this is the answer.

Comment: Hello, had the very same problem, I followed your issue and disabled Adblock Plus and it worked :)